# email notification tool with office365 support and text based two factor authentication

Tags: 18.04, kde, email, email-client, mail-notification

I am using Kubuntu 18.04. I have to need notifications tool or client with notification support for exchange based office365.

Our company forces two factor authentication with a sms text when logging in the account.

What i tried so far is:

**Kmail**: doesnt have two factor authentication support

**Thunderbird**: with mailnag support it seems fine but with a big monthly payment

**mailnag**:doesnt have two factor authentication support

Any ideas to get email notifications in any way? (:

Comment: FYI:  Kubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-reaches-end-of-kubuntu-support/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support;. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with KDE (*not Kubuntu*).

Comment: @guiverc i know (: But it is not the focus of the question.

Comment: My comment was an FYI, you're still on-topic on this site as the comment says.  I did **not** close vote your question.

Comment: @guiverc yes, i know, it is still on-topic, as written in here https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic. Thats why i asked. Thanks for your information and remind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found a solution after 5 days. **Franz** supports any kind of authentication about office365 mail(Franz is an isolated web view at the end of the day). Also it supports notification(with a minor bugfix that i made at local) and system tray.

==> https://meetfranz.com